# iOSアプリ: 英語のバッジが表示される

Tags: バグ, 再現性なし, 日本語

バッジの説明は日本語になっていますが、名前が英語のままです。

[image: App]

Comment: 現時点では、アプリは英語版しかないため、日本語版をまだ作っていないです。そのために日本語で使った場合、英語が残る箇所は多いと思います。将来にアプリも日本語化したら訂正します。

Answer (score 2):

supa さんがお教えくださいましたが、現在アプリを新しくダウンロードしようとしてもこちらの [iOS リンクは使えない](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/stack-overflow/id1155618808)ようで、SO英語版メタでは[アプリの開発が終了](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379742/7493042)したとも読みとれました。つきましては、本件のタグを[延期](/questions/tagged/%e5%bb%b6%e6%9c%9f)から[再現性なし](/questions/tagged/%e5%86%8d%e7%8f%be%e6%80%a7%e3%81%aa%e3%81%97)に変更させてください  。

---

以下、ご参考までに記しておきます。 m_ _m。
本件をご投稿いただきましてから6年以上経過しましたが、私の手元にあるデバイスでは未だに「Network Profile」のバッジ名は英語で表示されております。 ↓
[image: Network Profile]

しかし、なぜか「Feed」のバッジ名は日本語で表示されています。↓
[image: Feed]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 12 mini
- OS Version: 14.4.2

アプリの開発が再開する可能性については現在確認できておりませんが、何か情報が入りましたらこちらでシェアさせていただければと思います 。